# BiBTeX: I couldn't open file name 'myBib.aux'

Tags: bibtex, texshop

My article `paper.tex` compiles fine, but `myBib.bib` doesn't.

```
$ pdflatex paper.tex
$ bibtex myBib
I couldn't open file name `myBib.aux'
```

I happen to be using TeXShop, but the command line is unambiguous.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `bibtex paper` rather than `bibtex myBib`.

Comment: @NickVence `myBib.bib` is only a database, which may contain many entries that you don't cite in your paper. It's in `paper.tex` that you tell the system what bibliographic database to use (with `\bibliography{myBib}`). So it's `paper` which you must run BibTeX on (precisely `paper.aux`, but the extension can be omitted).

Comment: A solution can be found [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106525/31809) if you use a build subfolder for compiling.

Comment: important to do `pdflatex` _before_ `bibtex` -- took me some trial and error to realize

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In addition to Ian Thompson's comment, if you are using TeXShop then you don't even have to bother with the command line, as TeXShop provides you with a graphical interface. Just switch to BibTeX in the pop-up menu after a first LaTeX compilation, then press typeset (this is equivalent to calling `bibtex paper`in the command line) exactly as for a LaTeX compilation, then switch back to LaTeX and press Typeset (equivalent to command line `pdflatex paper.tex`; two compilations are needed).

Comment: i dont understand i've tried texshop and texworks and opening my .tex file with both and opening my .bib file with both and tapping typeset and nothing changes i still get [?] which is the same output i get with the green play button using textworks

Answer (score 16):

That will resolve the problem ;) :

```
pdflatex paper.tex
bibtex paper.aux
pdflatex paper.tex
evince paper.pdf
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, my latx file contains of many files. So when I tried to compile the bibliography.bib file directly without switching to the main document file (thesis.tex) I got the error. The solution is to compile the document from the main file (thesis.tex).
[image]

Comment: That's why they added the function "Options"->"Set current document as 'Master Document'". If you're clicking this while the main .tex file is open, you can compile everywhere