# Cannot run .bib file on TeXmaker

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texmaker

This question is indeed similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85075/bibtex-error-in-texmaker-i-couldnt-open-file-name-test-bb-aux): I open my Bibliographie.bib file in Texmaker and push the F11 button to "run" the file but then get

```
Process started

I couldn't open file name `Bibliographie.aux'

Process exited normally
```

My problem however was not solved by following the suggestions of the other post: I did go to > Option > Configure Texmaker
then click on the "Use a "build" subdirectory for output files"
and change the Bib(la)tex line to bibtex build\% 
(I also tried  "bibtex build/% -include-directory=build")

and that would just give me the same message:

```
Process started

I couldn't open file name `build/Bibliographie.aux'

Process exited normally
```

My bibliography file certainly has no inner mistakes since it worked perfectly on my old computer. The problem appeared as I changed to a new computer with a more recent version of Texmaker, but my files themselves have not changed.

**OOhhh:** I do not have any Bibliographie.aux file at least in the same directory as my other files... but as far as I remember, it was also the case in my old computer.

Comment: One of the reason why I never output files to some special build directory. It is simply confusing. Try to find out where the aux-file is and point bibtex to this folder.

Comment: I originally did not put the output files in any build directory but the problem came up anyway. And I don't remember that there were any more files than Bibliographie.bib for the bibliography itself. What I had was my main file ***.tex and then ***.aux and many other that appear when I compile the main file.

Comment: I bet your document is called something like `main.tex` or `thesis.tex` or `master.tex`. Run BibTeX wih arguments `main` or `thesis` or `master` or ..., but not `Bibliographie`.

Comment: I usualy don't use command lines, so I translate what I should do: open my main.tex file, and push the F11 button? that I actually already did: it actually works for the old references that I had added, but I have added a new one, and for this one, I would see [?] in the pdf file, so I thought I had to "run" the Bibliography.bib file

Comment: which is the way I have always done... and thas used to work

Comment: or, if I have to use the command line, someone has to recall me the exact sequence...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my mistake:  instead of "running" pdf lateX, I would just use the F1 button.

This is what I used to do with my old computer and I thought it was pdflatex compiling.

Every finally worked when I indeed run Bibtex = F11, then pdflatex = F6 (not F1), then again (F6)

Comment: F1 is quick build, you can configure what that does in the settings. Typically Quick build would run something like pdflatex + view pdf I think, but perhaps the settings are different in your system.