# How can I do Bibliography using Texmaker

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texmaker

I'm new in Texmaker and I want to make the bibliography and cite the reference I used at the end of my work, I made a file that contains the citation called "bibliographyCitation.bib" :

```
 @book{laouiti2014vehicular,
  title={Vehicular ad hoc networks for smart cities},
  author={Laouiti, Anis and Qayyum, Amir and Saad, Mohamad Naufal Mohamad},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@inproceedings{yousefi2006vehicular,
  title={Vehicular ad hoc networks (VANETs): challenges and perspectives},
  author={Yousefi, Saleh and Mousavi, Mahmoud Siadat and Fathy, Mahmood},
  booktitle={2006 6th International Conference on ITS Telecommunications},
  pages={761--766},
  year={2006},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{zhu2016collision,
  title={A Collision Avoidance Mechanism for Emergency Message Broadcast in Urban VANET},
  author={Zhu, Wanting and Gao, Deyun and Foh, Chuan Heng and Zhao, Weicheng and Zhang, Hongke},
  booktitle={Vehicular Technology Conference (VTC Spring), 2016 IEEE 83rd},
  pages={1--5},
  year={2016},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{oluoch2016distributed,
  title={A distributed reputation scheme for situation awareness in Vehicular Ad Hoc Networks (VANETs)},
  author={Oluoch, Jared},
  booktitle={Cognitive Methods in Situation Awareness and Decision Support (CogSIMA), 2016 IEEE International Multi-Disciplinary Conference on},
  pages={63--67},
  year={2016},
  organization={IEEE}
}
```

And my .tex file contains the document that I'm working on named "Bibliography.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for the horizontal lines, change thickness here

\center % Center everything on the page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADING SECTIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{KSU-LOGO}
\end{figure}

\textsc{\LARGE King Saud University}\\[1.1cm] % Name of your university/college
\textsc{\Large CSC 595}\\[0.1cm] % Major heading such as course name
\textsc{\large Seminar and Discussions}\\
\textsc{\normalsize Phase 3}\\[1.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries Bibliography}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document
\HRule \\[2.4cm]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AUTHOR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Student Name:}\\
Fatmah Hussain \textsc{AlQahtani} % Your name
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
Dr. Salah \textsc{Hammami} % Supervisor's Name
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[2.0cm]

% If you don't want a supervisor, uncomment the two lines below and remove the section above
%\Large \emph{Author:}\\
%John \textsc{Smith}\\[3cm] % Your name

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DATE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

{\large \today}\\[1cm] % Date, change the \today to a set date if you want to be precise

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LOGO SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\includegraphics{Logo}\\[1cm] % Include a department/university logo - this will require the graphicx package

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\vfill % Fill the rest of the page with whitespace

\end{titlepage}
\newpage
\LARGE Bibliography:\\[0.5cm]
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliographyCitation}

\end{document}
```

I made the options as the solution I found when I searched:

Commands Settings:
[image: Commands Settings]

Compiler Settings:
[image: Compiler Settings]

I saved all the files in the same folder.
When I compile the file I start with the .tex file with command "Quick Builder", then I compile the .bib file and I had this message :

```
Process started

I couldn't open file name `build/bibliographyCitation.aux'

Process exited normally
```

Then I compile again the .tex file with command "Quick Builder".
 And as a result after these steps, the bibliography didn't imported to my .tex file:(

Please could someone help me to know what is the problem. I checked every thing even the natbib package via MixTex Package Manager(Admin) I found it already there? I don't know where is the problem? I need a help from an expert:(

Thank you

Comment: Your tex file doesn't appear to have any `\cite` instructions. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Mico what I understand from my search is that I use \cite if I want to embed the citation within the text like> [1]. So, I don't know if this is right? Should I use it? does it affect the appearance of the bibliography in the document?

Comment: The entries contained in the bib file specified in the argument of `\bibliography` are *not* automatically included in the formatted bibliography. To generate citation call-outs *and* to have the entries listed in the bibliography, issue instructions such as `\cite{laouiti2014vehicular}`, where the argument should be the "key" to one of the entries in the bib file. The formatting and the call-out will depend on the bibliography style you use. In the case of the `plain` style, the call-outs will indeed be of the form `[1]`, `[2]`, etc.

Comment: @Mico I appreciate it! I compile it and had this as an output >>>[?]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "compile it"? Did you run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more?

Comment: @Mico yes, look I think that I got  where is the problem. [link] http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85075/bibtex-error-in-texmaker-i-couldnt-open-file-name-test-bb-aux . See what (David Carlisle) said and what (Skipper07) replied to him. I don't know how can I change the folder and where should I put it?

Comment: Have you tried reading TeXmaker's user guide?

Comment: @Mico No because I have to submit the file after 40 min from now:( that's why I want to solve the problem as quick as possible. Did you see (Skipper07)  comment ?! >>>[  
Your guess is right. I have just changed the settings that the .aux file shouldn't be written in a build folder and everything works fine...Thanks a lot...I was trying to solve it for last 2 days and you made my day.] I clicked on the Texmaker settings but I didn't find the place that I can change the .aux files directory to put it in the folder that holds my files that I'm working on

Comment: Using TeXStudio (a fork of TeXMaker) I have to mention once the *.bib bibliography file in the top *.tex file (\bibliography{foo.bib}, and to compile once completely. Then, the insertion of the citations via \cite{} is aided by autocompletion by TeXMaker.

Comment: @Mico  I'v just finished reading the user guide. But unfortunately, it didn't explain how to insert bibliography from a file