# Get citation undefined just in Texmaker

Tags: biblatex, citing, undefined

I need to use the predefined and created Latex project. When I run the project in Texmaker I got the warning **Citation on page 1 undefined** for the new reference that I added and the reference is not added. But when I run this project on Sharelatex the new reference is added.

I change  based on [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85075/bibtex-error-in-texmaker-i-couldnt-open-file-name-test-bb-aux/400060) the bib(la)tex command line property to:

```
bibtex build/% -include-directory=build
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you run the normal cycle: $(pdf)latex -> bibtex -> (pdf)latex (twice)`?

Comment: Recommendation: don't use a separate build directory. Just use a working directory. It seems tidier, but it just isn't worth it.

Comment: @ Bernard Yes. I did.

Comment: @ cfr could you explain more I did not understand your suggestion.

Comment: I think cfr is suggesting to use (only) `bibatex %` *and* to make sure that 'Use a "build" subdirectory for output files' is turned off/unchecked (it is the checkmark just above the first separator on the TeXmaker commands pane).

Comment: Any news here? Did you get thinks to work? What did you try?

Comment: @moewe I change my setting and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I change my setting and it works. [image: This is my new setting]

Comment: I would like to know which setting did you change in order to make it work. I have the same problem but my 'Use a "build" subdirectory for output files' is already unchecked so I don't think that is the key.

Answer (score 4):

I get citation undefined in Texmaker too.
And For answer to Sean Yun-Shiuan (which asking the setting that user34* changed)

That is what i did  :

Open setting -> go to compile fast 
- > choose the good one which look bib file too
-> rename the file if needed (bibtex-file.bib)

Like this gif : (sorry is in french --') 
[image]