# Help with refrences and couldnt open filename.aux

Tags: auxiliary-files

Ive done a search of the forums and tried the numberous  workarounds for this issue. I have a handin a week from now and could do with sorting this, it did work for a time then one day just stopped... (a likely story I know.)

I have my refrences and files in the same folder and am calling them by the same name

[image]

I have renamed the path in the config section

[image]

neither of these steps have helped as I still get the same error when I press F11.

Ive uninstalled miktex and texmaker reinstalled it, Ive used a different computer.

I'm open to any other suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Why does it think it should look in `build/` for the aux file?

Comment: As daleif said, your configuration for `Bib(la)tex` is wrong. Try removing the `build/` before `%`. // By the way, when this kind of error occurs, always try using the command line first to check if it is really the problem with tex itself.

Comment: advice from here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85075/bibtex-error-in-texmaker-i-couldnt-open-file-name-test-bb-aux

Comment: @Tam But you did not use `build` as the folder for output (that option in your screenshot is not checked).

Comment: Because you've not checked `[ ] Use a "build" subdirectory for output files` the aux-file is not generated in `build/` and so `bibtex` cannot find `build/testdoc.aux`. And because of this as Teddy already said: Remove `build/` before `%`.

Comment: @Teddy van Jerry how can I check the command line?  The issue still persists.

Comment: @Tam The command line usage can be as simple as `latexmk -pdf <tex file name>` which can automatically handle everything for you. But just as I previously said, remove `build/` before the `%` in your bib configuration should do.